# How to login into Web App with kerberos/AD but still allow access to non AD users

Tags: apache, active-directory, kerberos, mod-auth-kerb

I'm deploying a SSO in Apache webserver against an Active Directory via kerberos (mod_auth_kerb).

The module is installed and configured correctly, when I access apache websites with a logged in user to AD network, Apache receives correctly user's credentials via `REMOTE_USER` variable. The thing is that I want external users (non AD network ones) to be able to access Apache websites via regular login, but they get a

> 401 Authorization required

when accessing the websites.

I guess this can be achieved via kerberos configuration but haven't reached the solution. Does anyone know if this is posible with a kerberos location directive or should I configure some workaround for this, such as limiting location access by ip ranges in virtual host configuration Location directive?

My virtual host configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # General
    ServerAdmin packettrc@my.es
    DocumentRoot /home/moodle/moodle
    ServerName my.es  
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog logs/my.es-error.log
    CustomLog logs/my.es.log combined

    <Location />    
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName "Kerberos Login MY"

        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
        KrbServiceName HTTP/my.es@MY.ES
        KrbAuthRealms MY.ES  
        Krb5KeyTab      /etc/krb5.keytab

        require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in Apache? You could do it more elegantly in PHP. Speaking of which, this doesn't appear to be a PHP question

Comment: I guess you have no way to do this with php, an SSO with an AD user logged in must be done with kerberos, ntlm, cas server, etc... so the browser is able to send to the webserver the ADD logged in user credentials. In order to php know the remote_user apache must fetch it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
Require valid-user
```

with

```
Satisfy Any
```

You can find some insights in [this article](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/apache-kerberos-authentication). Just in case link to Apache's [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy).

Comment: Thanks let me some time to test your answer, I'm developing another solution right now.